# Is there any way to connect ms access database with ms word?

Tags: ms-access, vba, word-diff

I have a text box in access and a button, when i click on button, text box value open in ms word and when i edit values in ms word save and close then its automatically save in access texbox.

Can we connect the ms access object with ms word using connection string ?

Comment: this will be a bad concept!

Comment: please explain the point why this is bad?

Answer (score 0):

Better way perhaps: create a popup form with a large text field set to use Rich Text, assuming you don't have space on the master form for a big text box.